# Updating a react useState value does not work when calling useState twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-state

I started learning react yesterday and am having some trouble using the useState hook. The thing I am trying to do:

I have a list of challenges. Each challenge consists of an initialRound (string) and nextRounds (arr). I am trying to show the initalRound on the screen, and if there are any nextRounds, insert them as records with an initialRound in the deck. Each nextround will look like this: [index (int), roundDescription (string).

The for each loop to achieve this works. However, afterwards I want to remove the first challenge so the next challenge shows. This does not work however and it leaves me with an object undefined error on {challenges[0]['initialRound']}. If I leave the for each loop out, it does work as expected but I do not get the same nextRound formatting I try to achieve.

I hope I explained my case clear enough

````
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import deck from './data/challenges'

const GameScreen = () => {

  const [challenges, setChallenges] = useState(deck);

  const popChallengeHandler = () => {

    var currentChallenge = challenges[0]
    var nextRounds = currentChallenge['nextRounds']
    
    nextRounds.forEach(round => setChallenges((prevChallenges) => prevChallenges.splice(round[0],0,{
        initialRound: round[1],
        nextRounds: []
    })))
    
    setChallenges((prevChallenges) => prevChallenges.splice(1))

  }
  
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{challenges[0]['initialRound']}</Text>
      <Button onPress={popChallengeHandler} title="Next challenge" color="red"/>
    </View>
  );
}

export default GameScreen; ```
````

Comment: 1. Where is `prevChallenges` defined?
2. Is challenges supposed to be a 2D array?

Comment: @KenoClayton Thanks for the response.  1) prevChallenges is not defined before, I thought that by using this syntax, prevChallenges would automatically have the current value of challenges in it (before manipulation).  2) Challenges is not two dimensional, as it is an array of dicts. The dict has keys initalround (string) and nextrounds (arr)

Comment: In your code you haven't imported `useState`. In your call to `setChallenges` you could just have `setChallenges(challenges.slice(1))` rather than an anonymous function.

Comment: Yes you're right about the first point. In JS we don't really have a 'Dictionary' but instead generic objects. But I get what you mean. You should try to log the value of `challenges` to ensure it's properly structured before and after the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help. mattbbc something went wrong with the question formatting, I had imported useState, only made a mistake copying, thanks for ntoicing. @Keno Clayton I have added some console logging. Before and after the loop the values are as expected, only after setChallenges((prevChallenges) => prevChallenges.splice(1)), the challenges do not get sliced and stay the same

Comment: @mattbbc Your idea of changing it to setChallenges(challenges.slice(1)) instead of using the anonymous function works. Thanksalot. Why does it make a difference here?

Comment: @P200p your anonymous function is expecting a `prevChallenges` parameter, but nothing is actually being provided, so nothing is returned. Use of `slice()` instead of `splice()` is maybe personal preference but I feel it's more appropriate and reads better.

Comment: @mattbbc That makes alot of sense. Thanks for your help and getting back to me for an explanation